# Is there a term that refers to the observation that the quantum world is completely different from the non-quantum world?

Tags: soft-question

Is there a term that refers to the observation that the quantum world is completely different from the non-quantum world? Quantum physics is different from classical physics. I was wondering if there was a word coined by the scientists to refer to that very general observation.

Comment: Well, the world **is** quantum to the best of our understanding, so perhaps the observation is not that the classical world is different from the quantum world, but rather that the macroscopic quantum world is so well approximated by a classical model.  A semantic point, maybe, but to me it's one worth making.

Comment: Are you looking for just one word? Like a single noun or adjective? **Joking comment:** Hidden-variable models are annoyingly often called "realistic", so we could say we've observed that the world isn't realistic (locally). **Serious comment:** Classical physics can be regarded as a special case of quantum physics in which all observables commute with each other (if we allow the Hilbert space to be non-separable), so we could say we've observed that observables are non-commutative -- or in more physical terms, that not all observables are compatible with each other. But that's $>1$ word.